# Magento 2. Create customer account programmatically with no password and confirmation required

Tags: magento2, customer-account, bug, create

Context:

Account Confirmation is set to required from backend.

I'm creating a new customer account using `\Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagementFactory::createAccount()` method.

```
        $email = "jiro@example.com";
        $firstName = "Jiro";
        $lastName = "Ono";

        $customer = $this->customerFactoryData->create();

        $customer->setEmail($email);
        $customer->setFirstname($firstName);
        $customer->setLastname($lastName);

        // Make sure we have a storeId to associate this customer with.
        $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        $customer->setStoreId($storeId);


        // Associate website_id with customer
        $websiteId = $this->storeManager->getStore($customer->getStoreId())->getWebsiteId();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);

        $this->accountManagement->createAccount($customer);
```

Problem:

This successfully creates an user account. And send an email to the user to set their password. Problem is that I need confirmation on this client as well, but they are shown in grid as confirmed by default even if the user never sets is password or never opens mail or never enters the website.

I can't seem to find the logic that sets the client as unconfirmed. I suspect is a plugin or an observer.

Any tips or suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14492

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Stores -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration -> Create New Account Options**

Now Set **Require Emails Confirmation** to **Yes**

Clear cache.

[Update]

Overwrite **Magento/Customer/Model/AccountManagement.php** class.
Modify following method

```
/**
 * Send either confirmation or welcome email after an account creation
 *
 * @param CustomerInterface $customer
 * @param string $redirectUrl
 * @return void
 */
protected function sendEmailConfirmation(CustomerInterface $customer, $redirectUrl)
{
    try {
        $hash = $this->customerRegistry->retrieveSecureData($customer->getId())->getPasswordHash();
        $templateType = self::NEW_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REGISTERED;
        if ($this->isConfirmationRequired($customer) && $hash != '') {
            $templateType = self::NEW_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION;
        } elseif ($hash == '') {
            $templateType = self::NEW_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REGISTERED_NO_PASSWORD;
        }
        $this->getEmailNotification()->newAccount($customer, $templateType, $redirectUrl, $customer->getStoreId());
    } catch (MailException $e) {
        // If we are not able to send a new account email, this should be ignored
        $this->logger->critical($e);
    }
}
```

In your case **$hash** is empty. So change that logic.

Comment: Please read question carefully. Specially this part 'Account Confirmation is set to required from backend.'

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: Overriding the logic of this method will not solve the problem.
Sure a confirmation email will be sent but the confirmation token will be null as no confirmation token was generated.The general behavior will not change. Customers will still appear as confirmed even if they  never confirm their account.